# Returning a JSON containing an array in Vapor

Tags: vapor

Let's say I have Vapor configured with a database. I have two tables with a parent-child relationship. As an example let's use Team as parent table and Player as child one.

With Fluent it is easy to return a json with all the players of a team. It is also easy to return a json with the team of a player. But, which is the easiest way to return a json with the team properties and an array of players?

And the opposite. Given a json with the team properties and an array of players, which is the easiest way to create teams and players from that json?

Can Fluent help with that or should we manage it by ourselves?

Thank you very much!

Carlos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you create a special struct that conforms to `Content` to get the JSON data and return the JSON data. For your example, it would look something like this:

```swift
struct TeamPlayerContent: Content {
    let team: Team
    let players: [Player]
}
```

Then when you get the request, you can decode the body and get a struct instance:

```swift
router.post(TeamPlayerContent.self, at: "teams") { request, body in
    // Save the team and player models
}
```

And when you get the `Team` and `Player` data from the database, you can create a struct instance and return it from the route:

```swift
router.get("teams", Team.parameter) ( request in
    return try request.paramaters.next(Team.self).flatMap { team in
        let players = try Player.query(on: request).filter(\.teamID == team.requireID()).all()
        return players.and(team)
    }.map { data in 
        return TeamPlayerContent(team: data.1, players: data.0)
    }
}
```